# How can i parse multiple JSON Objects inside an array?

Tags: java, json

I'm trying to save each coordinate array from the JSONObjects inside "features" array, but as the objects are constantly updated, I have to find an automatic way to parse all the objects and use their coordinates to save them on a google maps point. (i want to parse it via java)

The JSON file (it updates so it will look different, that's why I'm looking for an automatic way, I want to save them to a LatLng in a MapsActivity)

```
{
"type": "FeatureCollection",
"features": [

{
"geometry": {
"type": "Point",
"coordinates": [
109198.840917,
100501.626971
]
},
"type": "Feature",
"id": "cortes_de_transito|71766",
"properties": {
"Motivo": "Obra",
"Tipo": ""
}
},

{
"geometry": {
"type": "Point",
"coordinates": [
102563.558027,
94833.763929
]
},
"type": "Feature",
"id": "cortes_de_transito|71785",
"properties": {
"Motivo": "Obra",
"Tipo": ""
}
},

{
"geometry": {
"type": "Point",
"coordinates": [
107047.021566,
102659.117425
]
},
"type": "Feature",
"id": "cortes_de_transito|74195",
"properties": {
"Motivo": "",
"Tipo": ""
}
}

]
}
```

and the java code, I've just parsed the "features" array

```
JSONArray main_array = response.getJSONArray("features");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just iterate `JSONArray` and get the `JSONObject`, It's again same thing get the `coordinates` array from each `JSONObject` the get the values from that `JSONArray`

```
for(int i=0; i<array.length(); i++) {
        JSONObject obj = array.getJSONObject(i);

        JSONArray ar = obj.getJSONArray("coordinates");

        for(int j=0; j<ar.length(); j++) {
            String co = ar.getString(i);
            System.out.println(co);
        }
    }
```